# Text overlapping with arrow used in tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum width=5ex,
    minimum height=5ex,outer sep=-5pt},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=1ex]{
            &     &     &     &  &  &  &  & \\
          \vdots     &  \vdots   &   \vdots  &   \vdots  & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \underline{E^k\textsf{ page}}\\
          k     &  H_{k}(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_{k}(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          k-1     &  H_{k-1}(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_{k-1}(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          k-2     &   H_{k-2}(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_{k-2}(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          \vdots     &  \vdots  &   \vdots  &   \vdots  & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots\\
          3     &   H_3(\Omega S^k)  &   0  &   0  & \cdots & 0 & H_3(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          2     &   H_2(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_2(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          1     &   H_1(\Omega S^k)  &  0  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & H_1(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          0     &  H_0(\Omega S^k)  & 0 &  0  & \cdots & 0 & H_0(\Omega S^k) &0 & \cdots\\
    \quad\strut &   0  &  1  &  2  & \cdots & k-1 & k & k+1 & \cdots \strut \\};
\draw[thick, ->] (m-11-1.east) -- (m-1-1.east) ;
\draw[thick, ->] (m-11-1.north) -- (m-11-9.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

Now as you can see on the top left-hand side of this image there is an overlap with the "k-2" and "k-1" and the "vertical axis". How can I make it so that these two things don't overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would right-align the nodes of the first column (since they appear to be labels), increase the column sep, which is achieved with

```
column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width("$k-2$"),align=right},column sep=2ex},
```

and shift the axes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum width=5ex,
    minimum height=5ex,outer sep=-5pt},column sep=1ex,row sep=1ex,
    column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width("$k-2$"),align=right},column sep=2ex},
   ]{
            &     &     &     &  &  &  &  & \\
          \vdots     &  \vdots   &   \vdots  &   \vdots  & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \underline{E^k\textsf{ page}}\\
          k     &  H_{k}(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_{k}(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          k-1     &  H_{k-1}(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_{k-1}(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          k-2     &   H_{k-2}(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_{k-2}(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          \vdots     &  \vdots  &   \vdots  &   \vdots  & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots\\
          3     &   H_3(\Omega S^k)  &   0  &   0  & \cdots & 0 & H_3(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          2     &   H_2(\Omega S^k)  &  0   &  0   & \cdots & 0 & H_2(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          1     &   H_1(\Omega S^k)  &  0  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & H_1(\Omega S^k) & 0 & \cdots\\
          0     &  H_0(\Omega S^k)  & 0 &  0  & \cdots & 0 & H_0(\Omega S^k) &0 & \cdots\\
    \quad\strut &   0  &  1  &  2  & \cdots & k-1 & k & k+1 & \cdots \strut \\};
\draw[thick, ->] ([xshift=2ex]m-11-1.east) -- ([xshift=2ex]m-1-1.east) ;
\draw[thick, ->] ([yshift=1ex]m-11-1.north) -- ([yshift=1ex]m-11-9.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]